# Can a table title be a Primary Key?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to retrofit some tables to an existing database.  The existing database has equipment numbers and I'm trying to add in tables with more information on that equipment.  Ideally, I'd like to make the table titles the ID numbers and set those as the PK of that table, making the ID numbers in the equipment list the FK.
Is it possible to set the table title as the PK?  Here's an example of one of the tables, and I'd like to make "E0111" the PK.

```
CREATE TABLE E0111(
EQUIPMENT Varchar(200), 
MAINTENANCE varchar(200),
CYCLE varchar(200)
);
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by making the table name the PK?

Comment: As long as it is a column with unique values then yes, you can make it a PK. That doesn't mean you should, there's no real advantage to be had there and with a varchar(200) the performance might be quite disappointing.

Comment: @Leeft the OP is talking about the table name (not a column). So this is impossible as far as I know.

Comment: Oops, right .. didn't even consider for a moment that Gary really wants to create a table for every type of equipment. And no, you can't do that. Keys (= one or more columns) can only point to other keys (= one or more columns).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this because the [primary key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) needs to be unique for every row of your table. If you "could" use the table name as the primary key it would be the same for every row.

You should use a unique column in your table as the primary key.

Also, I have no idea how you could achieve this with SQLite or any DBMS.

Comment: Yeah, i figured, I just didn't want the hassle of editing the original DB with all my extra rows. Thanks!

Comment: @GaryPivovarov Glad I could help, and like SEB told you, it IS worth the hassle ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing before I even get anywhere near answering the question about the table names being primary keys, we need to take a step back.

You should NOT have a table for each piece of equipment.

You need an Equipment table, that will store all of your pieces of Equipment together.  I assume you have that already in the existing database.

Hopefully it is keyed with a Unique Identifier AND an Equipment Number.  The reason for having a separate Unique Identifier, is that your database server uses this for referential integrity and  performance - this is not a value that you should show or use anywhere other than inside the database and between your database and whatever application you are using to modify the database. It should not typically be shown to the user.

The Equipment Number is the one you are familiar with (ie 'E0111'), because this is shown to the User and marked on reports etc.  The two have different purposes and needs, so should not be combined into a single value.

I will take a stab at what your Equipment table may look like:

```
EquipmentId int                -- database Id - used for primary key
EquipmentName Varchar(200)     -- human readable 
EquipmentDescription Text
PurchaseDate DateTime
SerialNumber VarChar(50)
Model Varchar(200)
etc..
```

To then add the Maintenance Cycle table as you propose above it would look like:

```
MaintenanceId int               -- database Id - used for primary key this time for the maintenance table.
EquipmentId int                 -- foreign key - references the equipment table
MaintenanceType Varchar(200)
DatePerformed DateTime
MaintenanceResults VarChar(200)
NextMaintenanceDate DateTime
```

To get the results about the Maintenance Cycle for all equipment, you then JOIN the tables on the 2 EquipmentIds, ie

```
SELECT EquipmentName, EquipmentDescription, SerialNumber, MaintenanceType DatePerformed
FROM Equipment
JOIN MaintenanceCycle ON Equipment.EquipmentId = Maintenance.EquipmentId
WHERE EquipmentName = 'E0111'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the name of the table a primary key.

All primary keys should be unique and a table column not table name. This is the general rule of thumb for a priamry key. There are plenty of resources on the internet about Primary keys.

Here are just afew:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp
http://database-programmer.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/database-skills-sane-approach-to.html

Comment: Yeah, i figured, I just didn't want the hassle of editing the original DB with all my extra rows.  Thanks!

Comment: @GaryPivovarov, it's worth the hassle!

Answer (score 0):

The name of a table should be descriptive of what is hold within it. See that data table as a drawer where you shall label what it contains.

In my humble point of view, the ID of an equipement shall only be labeled as-is on the equipement in question. Otherwise, in your database, it shall be the table `Equipments` that prevails with the ID of each piece of equipment you have.

Then, if you have other equipment-related information to save, add another table with the kind of information it shall contains, with the ID of the related equipment for which this information is saved.

For example, let's say we hold a maintenance schedule over your equipment.

**Equipments**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Id  |  Description  |  Location  |  Brand  |  Model
-----------------------------------------------------
1   | Printer/Copier|  1st Floor |  HP     |  PSC1000
```

**Maintenances**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Id  |  Description  |  Date |  EquipmentId  |  EmployeeId
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the EmployeeId column shall be there only if one requires to know who did what maintenance and when, for instance.

**MaintenanceCycles**

```
--------------------------------------------
Id  |  Code  |  Description  |  EquipementId
--------------------------------------------
1   |    M   |  Monthly      |  1
```

This way, every equipment can have its cycle, and even multiple cycles per equipment if required. This lets you the flexibility that you need for further changes.